# Customize Excel by VBScript

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, csv

I am giving my required Excel Template here. As my present scenario this excel will be stored in a fix path. But CSV will generate everyday.

My vb script should execute everyday to collect data from csv and write into this Excel , but small customization needed.

Here First 3 rows are Fixed Header, I need to convert csv and write values in excel from 4th row. but its obvious we have old data there. so it should delete 4th row to 7th row and put csv value as per required place. With proper border also.

Now tell me is it possible to modify my vbs to get this type of output?

to run the script like below ...
MyScript.vbs : which needs two argument to execute

```
cscript C:\Test\MyScript.vbs \\C:\Test\Sample.CSV \\C:\Test\Sample.xlsx
```

Original script is below. but I want to view like below screenshot.

```
srccsvfile = Wscript.Arguments(0)
tgtxlsfile = Wscript.Arguments(1)

'Create Spreadsheet
'Look for an existing Excel instance.
On Error Resume Next ' Turn on the error handling flag
Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
'If not found, create a new instance.
If Err.Number = 429 Then  '> 0
  Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If

objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

'Import CSV into Spreadsheet
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(srccsvfile)
Set objWorksheet1 = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

'Adjust width of columns
Set objRange = objWorksheet1.UsedRange
objRange.EntireColumn.Autofit()
'This code could be used to AutoFit a select number of  columns
'For intColumns = 1 To 17
'    objExcel.Columns(intColumns).AutoFit()
'Next

'Make Headings Bold
objExcel.Rows(1).Font.Bold = True

'Freeze header row
With objExcel.ActiveWindow
     .SplitColumn = 0
     .SplitRow = 1
End With
objExcel.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

'Add Data Filters to Heading Row
objExcel.Rows(1).AutoFilter

'set header row gray
objExcel.Rows(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
'-0.249977111117893
aList=Array("NOT ", "NO ", "NONE", "!")
For each item in aList
For Each c In objWorksheet1.UsedRange
    If InStr(1, c.Value, item) > 0 Then
        c.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
Next
next


'Save Spreadsheet, 51 = Excel 2007-2010
objWorksheet1.SaveAs tgtxlsfile, 51

'Release Lock on Spreadsheet
objExcel.Quit()
Set objWorksheet1 = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Header and Legend should be Fixed as screenshot.

But there can be alternate way also. If I can get some modified vb script which can create Header like the above screenshot (i.e. merge cell, border, freeze, remove gridlines) and add legend at the bottom, then I don't need to write into existing excel everyday. All-time when vbs executes it should replace old excel (if exist) with this proper format.

[image: Sample Excel output]

Comment: Add this line below `objExcel.Rows(1).AutoFilter`: 
**`objExcel.Columns.Autofit()`** and that should do the autofit trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

record a macro of creating the header and legend. then edit the code for clean up all the *.Select ... Selection* statements.  ... in your code that you posted, you can autofit all the columns with one command by using one of these

```
ActiveSheet.Columns("A:Q").AutoFit
ActiveSheet.Range(Columns(1), Columns(17)).AutoFit
```

Comment: Hi @jsotola can you paste the whole code here, exactly where I should fit Autofit code.... actually I am not familiar of these...